# Error while building the custom skill in Alexa Skill Kit [ASK]

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am writing one custom Alexa skill, in which sample utterances are  "{TeluguWord} in English" and "{EnglishWord} in Telugu".

For this, I created two slots EnglishWord and TeluguWord. I can see slots are crated used in the utterance. However, I am getting below error while building the model.

"Error building interaction model. A sample utterance references a slot that is not defined in the intent."

Any help to fix this error is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

As yours is custom slot you should create a custom slot in the custom slot section of interaction model else your utterance couldn't find the slot you have given

[image]

Please read about adding custom slots [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/custom-interaction-model-reference.html#custom-slot-syntax)

Comment: I have created the slots. Still, I am getting this error.

Comment: Can you please share screenshots of the custom slots, intents,  sample utterances?

Answer (score 0):

One of your sample utterances contains a slot that you haven't created or misspelled. You might have misspelled one of the slots in the sample utterances.

Example:

The slot name for this example is car

This doesn't cause a error: How much does a {car} cost?

But if you misspell it

This does cause a error:

What is the best {cra}?

If misspell it you will get a error.